# Missing return in a closure expected to return ''

Tags: swift

I have the following function:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, didTapMessageBubbleAt indexPath: IndexPath!) {

        super.collectionView(collectionView, didTapMessageBubbleAt: indexPath)
        let data = self.messages[indexPath.row]

        print("They tapped: "  + (data.text) + "- " + (data.senderDisplayName))

        rootRef.child("messages").child(data.senderId).child("score").runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
            // Set value and report transaction success
            if let myValue = currentData.value as? Int{
                currentData.value = myValue + 1
                return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
            }


        }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

    }
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
Missing return in a closure expected to return 'FIRTransactionResult'
```

At the beginning of this line:

```
}) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
```

But to the best of my knowledge, I am returning the required element in the previous lines in the function.

Could somebody help me figure out what I need to return to fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's complaining because according to the program, your conditional if-statement could return nil and thus nothing would be returned. Perhaps having an "else" statement which returns FIRTransactionResult.failure (if there is such a thing, I haven't worked with that before) would shut the compiler up.

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since my problem occurred following an if statement, I needed to include a failure case in the correct `FIRTransactionResult` form as such:

```
else {
     return FIRTransactionResult.abort()
}
```

And it fixed my issue.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Returning `FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)` in the if statement is causing the error. You should always return a `FIRTransactionResult`. For example:

```
    rootRef.child("messages").child(data.senderId).child("score").runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
        // Set value and report transaction success
        if let myValue = currentData.value as? Int {
            currentData.value = myValue + 1
            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }

        // you always need to return something.
        // Even if the `if` statement above is not executed
        return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

    }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```